# Removing fireplace mantle made out of drywall

Tags: fireplace, hearth

I'm wondering if I can remove the drywall looking mantle buildout and replace with a wood mantle? I'm guessing it would be easiest to leave the vertical drywall beams, but I'm not sure if it makes sense to remove those also. I'm assuming the built in mantle and vertical beams are hollow with just drywall around them, and maybe some metal cornering?

I'm mainly wondering what the best way to remove the current mantle so that I can put a wood one of the same or similar size in?.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!
[image]

Comment: drywall is fire resistant, wood is not

Answer (score 0):

Drywall cannot stand on itself, it needs "backing", which is construction-speak for wood (or metal) behind it. The drywall is then attached to this backing with screws. If you remove the drywall, you will be left with the backing, to which then you can attach any type of finishing material you like, including wood.

If you are making a custom mantle with wood from the lumberyard, you can either remove the drywall and use the backing as your template to attach new wood, or you can just screw/nail the wood on top of the drywall. Just use screws long enough to reach the wood backing.

If you are buying one of those pre-made mantles that they sell online, you'll have to remove the drywall and the backing, as they usually require a flat surface to which you attach a holding mechanism, and then the mantle to that holding mechanism. There's no way to guess how the backing of the current drywall was laid, so removing this can range from super easy to god-knows-what.

Answer (score 0):

Those posts with the beam on top are too ugly to be architectural. That top piece along the ceiling looks like a header. I can imagine a scenario where somebody put the jack studs and header outside the wall to avoid shoring while cutting an opening into a preexisting chimney. If I'm right, then the bases of those jack studs may have a very poor support under them and could require remediation. But maybe I'm just imagining things.